# How can we find the urls where an android apk sends request?

Tags: android, security, apk

I want to check whether an app is a spam app or not. For that I need to find out the urls it is sending requests to. How can I find out?

I had decompiled the app using apktool.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to sniff traffic, it's easier and faster. Load the apk on to an emulator instead of a device, then fire up a copy of Wireshark or tcpdump and watch the packets going out from the emulator. Depending on your configuration you can apply filters to narrow down the packets you're capturing.

Comment: any better emulator u suggest ?

Comment: @VivekSancheti I'm not sure I understand. There's only one Android Emulator. Comes with the SDK.

Comment: ok , but how but running app in bluestack and then testing it ?

Comment: @VivekSancheti Well actually you could use the X86 version of Android running on a virtual machine instead of an emulator. I suppose you could use bluestacks as well. The key thing is to have the apk running on a device with a network interface you can sniff. However you accomplish that is up to you.